# Java: access other windows title?

Tags: java, tcp, window

I am developing a Java API which has to connect with a TCP server running on my machine.
The TCP server's port changes at every launch.

This port is displayed on the TCP server's window title (see image below).

TCP server window:
[image: TCP server window]

I did not find any way to get the title of another process in Java. How can I do that?

Comment: What OS are you using?  This can be done with kludges that require use of JNI or JNA , but and are you sure that there is no other non-kludgy way of getting the port number from the server?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I can't think to another non-kludgy method to get the port. Having a fixed port would be the best, I might not be able to do it as the TCP server is not from me. What do you think about listing the process using TCP and picking the right one ?